# keeping position of button with changing page layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this anchor on my page but i also have another another button on the page when i click on it it opens a right side panel.

How can i adjust my anchor so that when the panel opens the anchor would move to the left and not stick inside the opened side panel.

```
<a style="display:none;" href="#topOfPage" class="scrollup badge swell light_up"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

how can i add: `right: 270px;` to the scrollup class so it will move when the other button is clicked?

css used for anchor:

```
.scrollup {
position: fixed;
bottom: 80px;
right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Please share the html you are using. It would be helpful to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with Jquery I guess you are using that to assign the `click` event add this on your function:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function(){
   $('.scrollup').css('right','300px'); /*Add this line original 25+275*/
})
```

Or you can add another class to the element and gain more control about the change like:

CSS

```
.move {
   right:300px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function(){
   $('.scrollup').addClass('move');
})
```

Comment: I followed your first code snippet and it is what i would like to do but is there a way to make it a toggle like? so once i click on '#yourbutton' the '.scrollup' will move to the right and when i click on '#yourbutton' again the '.scrollup' will go back to its original position.

Comment: yep my friend follow the second but instead of `addClass` use `toggleClass` @user3244544

Comment: @user3244544 nop mate add that class in your CSS file

Comment: for some reason when i create a '.move' class in my css file and call it in my js file it is not be displayed properly?

Comment: @user3244544 maybe you need more specificity can you reproduce your problem in jsfiddle? Have you checked the demo filie I did ?

Comment: i guess i had to clear my cache several times. Thanks! got it going!

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the width of the panel as the padding "right padding" of the button.
>
> Thanks.